# Global variable not working in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, global-variables, production

I have the following pair of controllers:

Admin::BaseController - used in the backend of the application.

Base::BaseController - used in the frontend of the application.

In Admin::BaseController I set the following global variable:

```
$FRONTEND = false
```

In Base::BaseController I set it as follows:

```
$FRONTEND = true
```

I do this so that I can do the following in various models:

```
def to_param
   If $FRONTEND
      ...
   else
      ...
   end
 end
```

This works in development but not in production.  I know that I should probably not be using global variables anyway.  What's a good alternative to this?

Answer (score 0):

create environment variable instead of that.
such as env['name ur variable']=value in environment.rb file

Comment: I can then change the environment variable within a controller? For example, I can set: env['front_end'] = true in environment.rb, and then change it to false from the admin::base controller?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Figaro gem to set Environment variables. Check it out here: https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro

It allows you to set dev and production variables really easily.

You can then access them using `ENV['name']` and the gem mentioned also adds them to your Heroku account too (Assuming you're hosting on Heroku)

Comment: Can I then change the environment variable within a controller? For example, I can set: env['front_end'] = true in environment.rb, and then change it to false from the admin::base controller?